# Meteor update behind proxy

Tags: meteor, proxy, catalog

I tried the following command:

```
$ export http_proxy=url:port
```

(also in capital letters) + the same with https

to avoid this error :

> Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

Nothing worked. I still have this error.

Is there someone that could help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Either you didnt run `meteor update` after your change or your proxy requires authentication  **user:password**.

From [wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy):

> Like a lot of other command-line software, the Meteor tool reads the
>   proxy configuration from the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY`
>   environment variables (the lower case variants work, too). Examples of
>   running Meteor behind a proxy:
>
> - on Linux or Mac OS X
>
>   ```
>   export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
>   export HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
>   meteor update
>   ```
> - on Windows
>
>   ```
>   SET HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
>   SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
>   meteor update
>   ```

Comment: I already tried this way, but I had an error because my password is ending with a '!' and the '!@' is used to call a variable and it says "cannot find environnement variable ...". I'll check again to be 100% sure, thank you for your answer

Comment: @Benobab I think you can escape it using :`'!'` or `'password!'`

Comment: and behind a SOCKS Host v5 configuration?